# Is it possible to use a color gradient as the color of the \rule command?

Tags: graphics, color, rules

I have an image which is just colors in a gradient pattern and I would like to apply this pattern to the `\rule` command instead of just choosing one color for it. Is it possible to use an image as the color of the rule? Like if the rule was a stripe cut off from the image.

Comment: You could include the image itself with an appropriate crop value to only select the colour gradient.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume [this is your image](http://themarklee.com/2013/11/29/get-started-css-gradients/) and call it `colour_gradient.png`:

[image]

You can crop out a portion of this image and use it as a rule in your document:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\rule{\linewidth}{10pt}

\clipbox{0 0 0 \dimexpr\height-10pt}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{colour_gradient}}

\end{document}
```

The above example sets a `\rule` of width `10pt`. Using `\clipbox` from [the `adjustbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox), we clip the bottom `10pt` from `colour_gradient.png` so that it resembles the colour gradient of the actual image. Depending on the layout of the image, you'll have to play around with the clipping dimensions.